# Pattern of exception handling in WCF in case of function having calls to too much other functions throwing Exceptions

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to know what is the best pattern for Exception handling in WCF service.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAnasageServerService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceFaultData))]
    FileConversionResponse ConvertDocument(FileConversionRequest request);
}
[DataContract]
public class ServiceFaultData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorDetails { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LogDetails { get; set; }
}
```

"ConvertDocument" having a lot more calling of Recursive functions throwing Exceptions.

**What I want :**
I want to know which function throw this exception but difficulty is due to recursiveness.i am unable to report which function throw this exception.

```
public static void convertDocument(List<AnasageServer.PagesTopics> PagesTopics)
    {

        try
        {
           Func1();
           Func2();
        }
        catch (FaultException<AnasageServer.ServiceFaultData> serviceFaultData)
        {
            Logger.log(serviceFaultData.Detail.Details);


            throw new Exception(" Conversion Failed! " + serviceFaultData.Detail.ErrorCode);
        }
```

I want to send error details back to client. But due to recursive-ness error details get overwritten and i am unable to report which function throw this exception.

More clearly,please see .[image: this diagram]

Answer (score 1):

When catching the exception, attach the original exception as the inner exception of the new throw.  The inner exception will maintain the original stack trace.

```
try
{
   Func1();
   Func2();
}
catch (FaultException<AnasageServer.ServiceFaultData> serviceFaultData)
{
    Logger.log(serviceFaultData.Detail.Details);

    throw new Exception(" Conversion Failed! " + serviceFaultData.Detail.ErrorCode,
        serviceFaultData);
}
```